# How to split conversations in Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

The conversation view in Outlook 2003 is handy but, unfortunately, it groups all messages with an empty subject (or just RE: and/or FWD: prefixes) into the same conversation.

I tried modifying the subject header of received messages (yes, it's an editable field) but they still group with the no-subject conversation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You explain the issue but what do you exactly need? Thanks.

Comment: I have several different email threads that were sent with an empty subject.  Outlook groups them into one "conversation".  I want to split them into several such that each "conversation" will only contain related email messages (replies and forwards).

Comment: I think that if you sort all of your emails by Subject (Which are blank) and then right click on the Subject bar at the top, select Group by box... I see all my email with no subject but with the sender I had the email conversations. Hope that help, let me know.